# How to adapt the path to everyone's, computer

Tags: c++, path

I have a C++ project that uses allegro, in the makefile i specify the allegro path wich is /usr/local/lib, but, what can i do to adapt it to everyone who have allegro installed in another path?
Also, within the program, i use absolute paths to load images because otherwise, it's imposible to run the program outside the project folder. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the user to modify an initial file before running the make.
But the usual way is to write a [configure script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) finding what you need to run the make.